# Circle values that don't match any of the ones in a dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created a dropdown list with values and assigned them to one of the columns in a table.

When I changed a few, then changed the name of items in the list and removed some I accidentally did some key combination somewhere around <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and Excel highlighted cells in the table that had a value not on the list.

The highlighting looks like a red oval around each such cell. How can I toggle it on and off?

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon, you might see an entry like this around data validation.
[image: Clear Validation Circles]

Check out [this article from microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010342173.aspx#BM3) for more information.